# How to configure Play for test environment

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I have an app in Play 2.6 and Scala and I want to configure all my Action to return Future or not, or i could say, to be Action or Action.async by a config file. So I could configure my entire app to work in production or test environment.
I have no clue how to do that. Hpw can I start to study and implement it?
Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: What do you mean? To have a production and test environment. On the test environment nothing is going to be async.

Comment: But why would you want to have a "test" environment if you aren't gonna be testing the same behaviour that is running in your production environment?

Comment: I'm afraid you are deeply misunderstanding Play - you can't go sync with it, it's async all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you're looking for something like [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#specifying-an-alternative-configuration-file) which would allow you to provide environment specific configuration values? Including [how to use those values in your controller](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#using-from-your-controller)

That document also covers [how to specify which `application.conf` to use via the command line](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file).

Comment: for example see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000310/play-framework-overriding-application-conf-values-based-on-environment/48012753#48012753